# Отправка смс из формы через sms.ru

Tags: sms

Нужно отправлять смс сообщение через html-форму, есть сервис sms.ru, но, как я понял, для использования API нужно быть либо ИП, либо Юр лицом. Есть похожие сервисы, где не требуются эти все формы собственности (ИП, ООО)
и есть ли какие либо упрощенные варианты, так как отправка идет на свой номер.

Comment: Я сам себе отправляю смски через smsc.ru, API есть

Comment: Так там написано, что Api можно использовать только юр лицам и ип

Comment: а как на свой номер отправлять и какой лимит в день?

Comment: Ничё не знаю, я не юр лицо и не ип, но API успешно юзаю, где вы такое вычитали вообще? Про лимит в день не в курсе, а в чём проблема отправки на свой номер — вы его прописать в поле «Кому» не можете что ли?

Comment: но, как я понял, для использования API нужно быть либо ИП, либо Юр лицом.
Интересно, а как они это проверят? Можно и вымышленное ООО указать, и реальное, но не свое.